# Special Character restrictions for TStringList Name-Value Pairs?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tstringlist

I have a TStringList that is loaded with a few thousand Name-Value Pairs.
One of them is
`004001000002000=Timbre2 Volume 0~127 4995`

I find a specific index by calling IndexOfName with the string '004001000002000'. I expect ValueFromIndex to return the string 'Timbre2 Volume 0~127 4995'

Instead, when I access this value using the ValueFromIndex, it returns the string:

```
~127 4995
```

What causes this? Is Tilde a special character that causes the string to be truncated? Can I set it to something else?

Comment: -1. Question does not exhibit the reported problem.

Comment: +1 to offset unwarranted downvote. The problem was obviously exhibited on the poster's machine, or the question wouldn't have been asked. The fact that the problem ended up being resolved in another way doesn't negate the fact the problem existed, and the answers here helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem using the following code in a `TButton.OnClick` event (Delphi 2007 and Delphi 7 - screen capture from Delphi 2007 test):

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('004001000002000=Timbre2 Volume 0~127 4995');
    SL.Add('ABCDEF=Testing 1 2 3');
    i := SL.IndexOfName('004001000002000');
    if i > -1 then
      ShowMessage(SL.ValueFromIndex[i])
    else
      ShowMessage('IndexOfName returned -1');
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This correctly shows the expected dialog:

[image: ShowMessage result]

I also tested using the simpler method:

```
    ShowMessage(SL.Values['004001000002000']);
```

This displayed the identical `ShowMessage` dialog.

Comment: Ack - my bad. I had some code later on that was trimming the first part of the return string off because I first tried to do this without value/pair by just matching the initial numeric part. It didn't work so I moved to the Value/Pair format, but forgot to remove the substring operation later on. Thank you both for your helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Tilde is not a special character to `TStringList`, unless you explicitally define it as one.

`TStringList.IndexOfName()` and `TStringList.Name[Index]` look only at what is in front of the first `NameValueSeparator` character, and `TStringList.ValueFromIndex[Index]` returns everything that is after the first `NameValueSeparator` character, the value is not truncated in any way.  `TStringList.NameValueSeparator` is set to `'='` by default.  So if you are seeing truncation occuring, then either you are truncating it in your own code, or the `TStringList` contains a line that actually says `'004001000002000=~127 4995'`.